# How to check if you have the asymptotic solution of some equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, analytic-combinatorics

Suppose I have a analytic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and I have the asymptotic expansion of some $x_0$ up to a few terms in terms of $\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \to 0$ which I believe is such that $f(x_0) = 0$. How can I prove that $$f(x_0) = 0$$

Some context - In my case, I am trying to compute the asymptotic expansion of the solution to some saddle point equation of form $f(x) = 0$, in order to apply the saddle point method from Asymptotic Analysis/Analytic combinatorics/analytic number theory. However, actually computing the solution to this equation seems difficult. Instead, I want to 'guess' the solution to the equation, and prove that my guess is correct. Is this possible?

Comment: Incomprehensible. What does "asymptotic expansion of $x_0$" mean?

Comment: $x_0$ is some function of $\epsilon$, and its asymptotic expansion $\tilde{x}_0$ is a polynomial in $\epsilon$ upto some degree (say $k$) such that $x_0 - \tilde{x}_0 = O(\epsilon^{k+1})$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: OK. Let's look at a simpler question. Suppose that instead of an asymptotic expansion for $x_0$ as a function of $\epsilon$, you had the exact value of $x_0$, say, $17$. So now you have an analytic function $f$, and you want to know how to prove $f(17)=0$. Well , how you prove $f(17)=0$ is going to depend a lot on what you know about $f$, isn't it? What shape of answer are you expecting to your question?

Comment: Suppose $f(\tilde{x}_0) = O(\epsilon^{k+1})$. Prove that there exists $x_0$ such that $\tilde{x}_0$ is the asymptotic expansion of $x_0$ and $f(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Is that a new question? To me, it doesn't look the same as the question you posted. Also, $x_0$ is, you write, a function of $\epsilon$, and that makes $f(x_0)$ a function of epsilon, so when you write $f(x_0)=0$ you want that to be true for all $\epsilon$? Won't that just make $f$ identically zero?

Comment: It is the same question, I was just clarifying the definitions since you asked. No, $f$ shouldn't be identically $0$, since $f(x_0) = O(\epsilon^{k+1})$.

Comment: simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356960/how-to-check-if-you-have-the-asymptotic-solution-of-some-equation